# How to overload operator [][]

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operators

My question is how i can to overloading operator [][] ?
In addition what happening Behind the Scenes when i call to the extension of the operator?

Comment: Neither of those are single operators.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c?rq=1

Comment: BTW, this question smells like a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). You may get more useful answers when you tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please don't "overload" `--->`. You could maybe do it with an `operator--(int)` that returns a proxy that has `operator->`, but such unusual syntax is highly confusing.

Comment: @Murphy i try to find a general solution for that problem. i work on project which uses in matrixes with diffrent dimensions, i found solution for the 2-demnsions problem but for the n'th demension problem i dont find and my solution dont help me to understand how to extend it for n'th dimension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct term is operator *overloading*.

To implement some sort of `[][]` requires your returning a proxy object for the first `[]`, on which the operator `[]` is again overloaded.

Chains of `()()` can be done in a similar way.

For the *slide operator* genre, see [What is the "-->" operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-operator-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: thanks, do you know what happening behind the scene? for the ability to extend it for **n**'th []

Comment: Well, the proxy object could be a template templatised on the *degree". This could get quite messy though. Why not use `()` with a variable argument list?

Comment: If they ever expand `operator[]` to accept multiple arguments for user defined types, I'll be a happy camper

Comment: The `[]` solution is better if the intermediate objects make sense. Eg if a 2D array's `operator[]` returns a reference to a 1D array that is fully functional on its own. If you would have to create proxy objects, I prefer the use of `operator()`.

Comment: @patatahooligan - I don't like it. It feels weird to overload the function call operator on something that isn't a functor... Though I suppose one could argue that a matrix is a function from ordered pairs of indices to the underlying field... so IDK.

Comment: @Bathsheba A view object is what I was thinking of too. What I mean is that it should offer full functionality, such as being copied from or assigned to/from a 1D array. I don't like solutions where the proxy objects only exists to provide `operator[]` so that you can write `array2D[x][y]`, but `array2D[x]` doesn't do what you would expect it to.

Comment: @StoryTeller Fair enough, some people like `operator()` to only mean function. You can generalize my stance to: I would prefer a non-`operator[]` solution to an `operator[]` that returns a proxy object whose only functionality is to offer an `operator[]` of its own.

Answer (score 1):

The operators `[][]...`, `()()...`, and `-->` (as for the last, I am assuming you did not mean `--->`) are not actually c++ operators, but a combination of c++ operators.

For example `[][][]`, applies `[]` to the lvalue, and returns a certain lvalue, to which `[]` is applied again, and then the same for the third time.  So there is no actual `[][][]`, but it is simply `[]` applied 3 times.

```
int a[2] = {0,1};
int b[3] = {2,3,4};
int *c[2] = {a,b};

c[0][1]; // [0] first extracts 'a' from 'c', then [1] extracts 1 from a (the value in the second index).
```

The same goes for `()()()`.

`-->` Also follows the same idea, except that here it is not a repeated combination of the same operator, but a combination of `--`, which will return the lvalue and then decrease it by 1, and `>`, which will compare the left hand side with the right hand side.